# How to check if the user is admin?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to use the latest version of Firebase and Angular. Overall concept I am trying to achieve is admin authentication. I have achieved login logout functions and have saved the googleAuth login user to database with UID. 
And I am trying to restrict some pages to Logged in and Admin. I have assigned isAdmin: true as a value in the user object that is stored in the database. I want to see if the user is admin and return true or false for the router params.

Here is what I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
user.service.ts

export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }
 get(uid:string): FirebaseObjectObservable<AppUser>{
   return this.db.object('/users/' +uid);
 }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import{NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BsNavbarComponent } from './bs-navbar/bs-navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { OrderSuccessComponent } from './order-success/order-success.component';
import { MyOrdersComponent } from './my-orders/my-orders.component';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard as AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AdminAuthGuard as AdminAuthGuard } from './admin-auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BsNavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    OrderSuccessComponent,
    MyOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent}, 
    {path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent},
    {path: 'shopping-cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'order-success', component: OrderSuccessComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'my/orders',component: MyOrdersComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]},
    {path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]}  
  ])    
],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

admin-auth-guard.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
   return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid)),
    map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin)
  );

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this to show the average user whether he is permitted to access the page or not is okay. But this must be done with security rules. If not any user will be allowed to hijack the Javascript page and make himself an admin and get access to the secret pages not meant for the average user.

A cleaner way to do this is to have a top list of objects that contains the userid of all the permited users. And check against the list. This list must be read only or can only be accessed by admin. Which is done by security rules.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ho Wei Lip. I have visited the link that you mentioned  But didn't get anything. Can you please explain how to do that?? how should be done that practically??

Comment: For a start in your case I will not let anybody or only specific users to access the variable isAdmin and sensitive admin data. How to do that can be easily found on that link. But how to do it specifically really depends on your overall design of your project.

Comment: Yes I understood the mistake. I didn't added the isAdmin property to database. now I have added it and set it to true. now it is showing expected output.it was the silly one but it took me lot of time to figure it out:D Btw thank you so much for your response@Ho Wei Lip

Comment: Glad that you solve it. Good luck for the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

Did you used displayname property? When doing user or admin registration you can add this property and it will save in authentication db . So in your login function you can check using if displayname property is admin or user. It’s simple and easy method.